# Matlab question: usage of save

Tags: matlab

In the following matlab code,

```
random_numbers = randn(1,1000);
j=1;
for i=1:length(random_numbers)
if random_numbers(i) > 2.0
extracted(j) = random_numbers(i);
j = j + 1;
end
end
save 'sample1' extracted
```

we get the following error:

```
??? error ==> save
Unable to write file sample1: permission denied.

error ==> test at 9
save 'sample1' extracted
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `permission denied` error would suggest that you are trying to save to a directory to which you do not have write permission. Since you have specified just a base name for the filename, `save` will try to save the MAT-file to the current working directory, which you can determine by running the command `pwd`. You can also check the permissions of the current directory by running

```
[success, message] = fileattrib
```

and inspecting the `UserWrite` field of the returned `message`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This can be fixed by changing the current directory. Use pwd to check the current diretory

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
save('sample1', 'extracted');
```

or:

```
save sample1 extracted
```